# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar un método desde el metodo main?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy usando NetBeans, en una pestaña tengo el método main y desde ahí quiero iniciar un método de otra pestaña el mismo package.

**Metodo main:**

```
import java.lang.Math; 


public class Practica3 {
    public static void Main(String args[]){
        
        Garaje Practica3 = new Garaje();
        
        
        Coche CocheUno = new Coche();
        Coche CocheDos = new Coche();
        
        CocheUno.Marca = "Audi";
        CocheUno.Modelo = "A8";
        
        CocheDos.Marca = "Ford";
        CocheDos.Modelo = "CMax";
        
        Garaje.aceptarCoche(int coche, int averiaAsociada, boolean Lleno, int CochesTotales);
        
    }
}
```

**Pestaña con el metodo:**
Quiero iniciar el metodo "*aceptarCoche*"

```
package P3;


public class Garaje {

    
    private String coche;
    private String averiaAsociada;
    private int CochesTotales;
    
    private boolean Lleno;
    
    
    public Garaje(){
    
        Lleno = false;
    
    
    }
    
    

    public static void aceptarCoche(int coche, int averiaAsociada, boolean Lleno, int CochesTotales){
        if(Lleno == true){
            System.out.println("El garaje esta lleno.");
        }else{
          
            Lleno = true;
            
            int LitrosAceite = Motor.getLitrosDeAceite();
            
            //Averia falta de aceite, llena deposito.
            if(LitrosAceite == 0){
                LitrosAceite = LitrosAceite + 10;
                System.out.println("Llenando deposito de aceite...");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Averia desconocida");
            }
            
            CochesTotales++;
            double rand = Math.random();
            System.out.println("Factura:" + rand);
            Garaje.devolverCoche(Lleno);
            
        } 
    
    }
    
    private static void devolverCoche(boolean Lleno){
    
        Lleno = false;
        System.out.println("Garaje vacío");
    }
}
```

He probado quitando static y cambiando las variables que recibe pero sigue marcando error. Aunque ponga el contenido del método en la clase del main continua el error.
Adjunto mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: El problema está en que cuando llamas a un método los parámetros tienen que ser valores. Te recomiendo que repases el concepto de parámetro. La mayoría de parámetros que tiene el método `aceptarCoche` no los usas en el código que aparece.

Comment: Hola Adrian la llamadas de métodos en otras funciones como regla simple se hacen a través de la variable instanciada  de la clase `Garaje Practica3 = new Garaje();` en tu caso la variable de llama `Practica3` como buena practica las variables van con inicio en minúscula podrías renombrarla `Garaje garaje= new Garaje();` y para utilizarla `garaje.aceptarCoche`, sino la renombras para utilizarla seria `Practica3.aceptarCoche`,  como vez la llamada es sobre el nombre de la variable no la clase.

Comment: @Roberto E Moran el método está declarado con el modificador `static`. Aunque ciertamente no debería ser un método `static` y la llamada tendría que hacerse como dices en caso de que no lo fuese.

Comment: Tienes razón como vi que instanciaste la clase creí que los métodos no eran estáticos, seguramente el error es porque no has colocado parámetros a la llamada de método `Garaje.aceptarCoche(1, 2, true, 2);`.

Comment: El método `main` tiene que escribirse todo en minúsculas o no funcionará

Comment: Al llamar al metodo aceptarCoche no le pongas el tipo de la variable. Debes llamarlo simplemente:  Garaje.aceptarCoche(coche, averiaAsociada, Lleno, CochesTotales)